# Remove SWF file after loading a Different SWF file using "Loader" in Flash (AS3)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am trying to load multiple swf files. But the problem is that whenever I load them (back and forth; vice-versa), my file keeps on slowing down. I looked a solution from the internet, such as using "unload" and "removeChild" but I can't get a clear solution and I don't know where to put it. Any help is very much appreciated..Here's my code on how I load my swfs:

**MainMenu.swf:**

```
//***************CLICK GALLERY*********************//
Gallery_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, Gallery);

function Gallery(event:MouseEvent):void{

    var ldr1:Loader=new Loader();
    ldr1.load(new URLRequest("Gallery.swf"));
    addChild(ldr1);

}
```

**Gallery.swf:**

```
//***************CLICK QUIT******************//
Quit_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, Quit);

function Quit(event:MouseEvent):void{

    var ldr1:Loader=new Loader();
    ldr1.load(new URLRequest("MainMenu.swf"));
    addChild(ldr1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use removeChild and remove every listener. You can unload swf by calling unload on your loader or unloadAndStop.

You can read this article for more information.

[UnloadAndStop from Adobe](http://helpx.adobe.com/flash/kb/flash-player-10-action-script.html)

[Unload SWF](http://www.flashandmath.com/intermediate/swfload/unloading.html)

Comment: @Nambew-- Thank you for your help and reply. But all the examples I saw are just unloading the file whenever a button is clicked. What I think is that by clicking a button in "MainMenu.swf", it will add the "Gallery.swf" and at the same time,  it will also unload it. I tried to add "ldr1.unloadAndStop()" after the "addChild(ldr1)" but still don't work. Is it possible this way?